# How to click the "from clipboard" popup in Android 10 in an Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-10.0

We have tests that require confirming copy/pasting works. We are seeing the clipboard pop-up introduced in Android 10 (seen below) displayed instead of the "paste" dialog that has historically displayed. Issue this created is that it's unclear how to click the dialog. If someone has a suggestion please share it.

Used Layout Inspector, but that doesn't display any data about the pop-up. Also tried

```
onView(withText("from clipboard"))
            .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
            .perform(click())
```

yet no success.

[image: clipboard pop-up screenshot]

Comment: How did you make it appear? Can you please show what you wrote for the EditText? Can you reproduce it on a new project too?

Comment: Seems to pop-up after copying text. Not really certain exactly how that pop-up works

Comment: Can you please share code of the EditText alone? I want to see it appear on device/emulator. Or even a sample POC that has it? You can upload to some random server if you wish... For some reason I didn't see it for my EditText, but I saw it on other apps...